# How to convert string into datetime format in salesforce apex code?

Tags: datetime, salesforce, apex-code, apex

I want to change datetime format so that first of all I got datetime and after that I have convert it to string with different format. Now I want to again convert this into datetime format but this gives an error, invalid date time.  My code is:

```
DateTime startDT2 = DateTime.newInstance(selectedDate.addDays(1), initialEndTime);
system.debug('select dt2>>>'+ startDT2); **output**=2014-12-09 8:00:00

String myDate = startDT2.format('M/d/yyyy h:mm a'); 
system.debug('select mydate>>>'+ myDate); **output**=12/9/2014 1:00 AM
Datetime dt = Datetime.valueOf(myDate);
system.debug('date_string >>>'+ dt);    **output**=invalid date/time
```

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [Datetime.valueOf()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm?SearchType=Stem&Highlight=Datetime%7CDatetimes%7CDateTime%7CDATETIME%7CdateTime%7Cdatetime#apex_System_Datetime_valueOf):

> The specified string should use the standard date format “yyyy-MM-dd
>   HH:mm:ss” in the local time zone.

You can't use `12/9/2014 1:00 AM` string and convert it to Datetime.

Answer (score 1):

If the users locale is English (United States) then you can use the [DateTime.parse(string)](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_parse) method:

> Constructs a Datetime from the String datetime in the local time zone and in the format of the user locale.
>
> **Example**
>   This example uses parse to create a Datetime from a date passed in as a string and that is formatted for the English (United States) locale. You may need to change the format of the date string if you have a different locale.
>
> ```
> Datetime dt = DateTime.parse('10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
> String myDtString = dt.format();
> system.assertEquals(myDtString, '10/14/2011 11:46 AM');
> ```

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) site is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.